# Using a DataTable object with Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, datatable

I have an interesting problem: I can get results back from my WCF service to my Silverlight code as a DataTable.  Problem is, Silverlight doesn't support DataTable objects.  I've been poking around with what I can do, and the best I can come up with is passing it back as a List.

Great, right?  Nope.  Now I'm getting the same problem as before; nothing get returned.  Code shows it as working properly, but it just doesn't return anything at all.

Any advice as to how to go about this?  I need to be able to grab the database results, and work with it in Silverlight.  Currently, I can get the data in an object type not supported by Silverlight, but that sort of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Using a DataTable is not recommended with a Web Service as DataTable is not interoperable with other language that are not .NET compliant.

You should reconsider the return type of your web service.

See if a [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) with WCF could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight like entities. Figure out the entity. Make another wcf service which calls the first one. Do your magic inside the 2nd wcf service - convert the datatable into an entity. And then from your silverlight call the second wcf service...

Answer (score 0):

Can you postmore information on your WCF service?

Have you defined a data contract?

```
[DataContract]
public class Vendor
{
    [DataMember]
    public int VendorID;

    [DataMember]
    public string AccountNumber;

    [DataMember]
    public string Name;

    [DataMember]
    public int CreditRate;

    [DataMember]
    public int PreferredVendorStatus;

    [DataMember]
    public int ActiveFlag;

    [DataMember]
    public string PurchasingWebServiceUrl;

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate;
}
```

A data contract is necessary for the service to serialize your objects and for the client to know how to reassemble the object